# How to retrieve elastic net coefficients?

Tags: r, r-caret

I am using the caret package to train an elastic net model on my dataset modDat. I take a grid search approach paired with repeated cross validation to select the optimal values of the lambda and fraction parameters required by the elastic net function. My code is shown below.

```
library(caret)
library(elasticnet)

grid <- expand.grid(
      lambda   = seq(0.5, 0.7, by=0.1),
      fraction = seq(0, 1, by=0.1)
    )

ctrl <- trainControl(
      method     = 'repeatedcv',
      number     = 5,  #folds
      repeats    = 10, #repeats
      classProbs = FALSE
    )

set.seed(1)
enetTune <- train(
          y ~ .,
          data = modDat,
          method = 'enet',
          metric = 'RMSE',
          tuneGrid = grid,
          verbose = FALSE,
          trControl = ctrl
        )
```

I can get predictions using `y_hat <- predict(enetTune, modDat)`, but I cannot view the coefficients underlying the predictions.

I have tried `coef(enetTune$finalModel)` but the only thing returned is NULL. I am suspecting that I have to give the `coef()` function more information but not sure how to do this.

In addition, I would like to produce a box plot of the 50 sets of coefficients (10 repeats of 5 folds) associated with the optimal lambda and fraction parameters.

Answer (score 3):

To see the coefficients, use `predict`:

```
predict(enetTune$finalModel, type = "coefficients")
```

See `?predict.enet` for more information on how to get specific coefficients.

Comment: It appears that I get coefficients for many values of lambda, which I do not find intuitive. Furthermore, the values of lambda are not limited to those specified in the grid object.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from the answer by @Weihuang Wong, you can get the coefficients from the final model using the following code:

```
predict.enet(enetTune$finalModel, s=enetTune$bestTune[1, "fraction"], type="coef", mode="fraction")$coefficients
```

Answer (score 1):

To me what works best is `stats::predict`, as is @Weihuang Wong answer. However, as OP pointed out in a comment, that provides a list of coefficients for every value of lambda tested.

The important thing to understand here is that when you are using `predict`, your intention is precisely to **predict** the value of the parameters, and not really to retrieve them. You should then be aware of that an explore the options available.

In this case, you could use the same function with the argument `s` for the penalty parameter lambda. Remebember that you are still predicting, but this time you will get the coefficients you are looking for.

```
stats::predict(enetTune$finalModel, type = "coefficients", s = enetTune$bestTune$lambda)
```